# Общедоступный сервер mirror unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал делать мультиплеер с mirror по видео. После того как сделать пошел проверять подключится на разных компах, не вышло. Почему? У меня мультиплеер только для игроков подключенной к одной сети? Как сделать, чтобы любой кто скачал мою игру подключался к одному серверу? Это возможно с mirror?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это из-за NAT, гугли "NAT punchthrough". В двух словах, оба компьютера, которые надо соединить находятся за брандмауэрами, они не дают компьютерам соединиться на прямую. Обязательно нужен некий сервис-посредник для преобразования адресов. Для Mirror вот такие варианты есть: https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/transports#relay-transports